# Error while starting up liferay

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6

I am using liferay 6.2 GA2. I was creating some web content portlets and Fremarker templates using liferay UI. I started getting sudden error on the console saying

```
12:26:22,880 WARN  [DefaultDeviceRecognitionProvider:37] Device recognition provider is not available.
```

This was infinitely getting printed on my server console ,I tried navigating to "localhost:8080"  in all the browsers and saw errors as below :

1. IE : Cannot display the page
2. Chrome :"This webpage has a redirect loop"

I researched on the web and tried below things

1. Tomcat server restart
2. Cleaning up tomcat work and temp dir
3. Mysql service restart
4. Cleaning up browser cache and cookies
5. Tried direct logout URL for liferay

After spending hours on this ,I cleanup up the lportal db and started with fresh instance of db and it worked.

Could anybody please help me understand what might be the issue?

As this cleaning up database solution is something I cannot try in production. Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you specify a bit more what you actually did? Right now you're saying *I did something, now it doesn't work any more - what did I do wrong?* . It would help to know if one of the templates or content articles interfaces with the device recognition for example. Where did you actually get the templates from? Did you install the device recognition plugin (WURFL) from marketplace?

Comment: I did not install any device recognition plugin (WURFL) ,all I did was creating sample web content with 2 text type fields in structure and a freemarker template to iterate them and display their value.There were  few syntactical errors in freemarker template which I was resolving.The only event happened between the point it was working and it stopped working was session time out.System was idle around an hour,after which I saw errors on server console and application did not come up at all after that.Please let me know if any more details are needed.Thanks.

Comment: I did face this issue before, in our case we were having one portlet which was having URL redirection rule and when that particular portlet's deployment failed we had same issue.Once we resolved deployment issue for that portlet everything started working. I don;t know whether it will help you or not but thought of sharing.

Answer (score 0):

May be when the first time you unzipped your bundle, some file might have been corrupted..

Comment: It was all working fine for around a month after I unzippped liferay bundle.